# Intermittent build failures of Ruby app with MongoDB 3.4 on Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, travis-ci

We have been using the default MongoDB version in our Travis builds, which is 3.2. After upgrading to MongoDB 3.4 (3.4.10) we have started seeing intermittent build failures:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

Mongo::Error::OperationFailure:
  Didn't find RecordId in WiredTigerRecordStore (28556)
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/operation/result.rb:256:in `validate!'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/operation/write/write_command_enabled.rb:57:in `execute_write_command'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/operation/write/write_command_enabled.rb:41:in `execute'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/index/view.rb:159:in `create_many'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/index/view.rb:130:in `create_one'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/indexable.rb:38:in `block in create_indexes'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/indexable.rb:31:in `each'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/indexable.rb:31:in `create_indexes'
# ./config/application.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Application>'
# ./config/application.rb:60:in `each'
# ./config/application.rb:60:in `block in <class:Application>'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `block in execute_hook'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:73:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:13:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

In our application.rb (line number 60) we make sure that we create all the relevant MongoDB indexes:

```
User.create_indexes
```

**Versions**

- MongoDB: 3.4.10
- Ruby: 2.3.5 (MRI)
- Rails: 5.1.4
- Mongoid: 6.2.1 (mongo 2.3.4)
- Travis build environment: Trusty (sudo-less)

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17510 but they are using MongoDB 3.0

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio That issue (SERVER-17510) was fixed over two years ago in version 3.1.0, we're running 3.4.10.